# SharedKeyCredential is not a constructor - Azure Blob Storage + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to delete an image in my aucitonImages container, but when I execute the function from postman, I get `SharedKeyCredential is not a constructor` I've been following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs-legacy) and I think I have everything setup, but I don't see what's different in my code from the docs. I appreciate any help!

```
app.delete("/api/removeauctionimages", upload, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { ContainerURL, ServiceURL, StorageURL, SharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
  const credentials = new SharedKeyCredential(process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY);
  const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(credentials);
  const serviceURL = new ServiceURL(`https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`, pipeline);
  const containerName = "auctionImages";
  const blobName = "myimage.png";



  const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, containerName);
  const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, blobName);
  await blockBlobURL.delete(aborter)
  console.log(`Block blob "${blobName}" is deleted`);

});
```

Comment: What version of Azure Storage Node SDK you're using?

Comment: ```"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.1.0"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the SDK Version 12.1.0 documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest), looks like Microsoft changed `SharedKeyCredential` to [`StorageSharedKeyCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/storagesharedkeycredential?view=azure-node-latest).

Can you try with that?

Also, please see the samples for this version of SDK here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript.

---

Here's the code I wrote using v12.1.0 of Node SDK:

```
const { StorageSharedKeyCredential, BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY);


const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential
);

const containerName = `temp`;
const blobName = 'test.png';
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
await blockBlobClient.delete();
```

Comment: I get ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newPipeline' of undefined```. Here's what I changed: https://pastebin.com/T7d61V1A

Comment: Please see the sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/sharedKeyCred.js. The code you're writing is for version 10 of the SDK. I believe a lot has changed between v10 and v12.

Comment: I updated my code and got it working to delete the container with this code: https://pastebin.com/TFuM7Wwf  but my goal is to delete the url of the image inside the container based on it's url. How can I delete by URL in v10 and not the whole container?

Comment: I updated my code to try and delete by URL, but it's saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromContainerURL ' of undefined. I'm reading the docs for v10. https://pastebin.com/nmKTYS2s  Any suggestions? I'm following this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs-legacy