# StorageSharedKeyCredential is not a constructor: vue.js + azure-blobStorage

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-blob-storage

When trying to connect to azure-blob-storage and trying to wrap the connection information and using [StorageSharedKEyCredential] I got the following error:

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential is not a constructor
```

I'm using Vue.js.

There is a similar problem that the version is different, so I checked the document and version.
(Used version: "@ azure / storage-blob": "^ 12.1.1")

How can I use StorageSharedKEyCredential?
Finally I want to be able to access Azure Blob Storage.
Please let me know.

===========================
Code is this.

```
const { StorageSharedKeyCredential,BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

mounted: function () {
  this.init()
},
methods: {
  init: function () {
    this.accessBlob()
        .then(() => console.log('Done'))
        .catch((ex) => console.log('catch:', ex.message));
    },
  accessBlob: async function(){
      const config = require("./config/config.json");
      const ACCOUNT_NAME = config.storageAccount;
      const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = config.storageAccessKey;

      // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
      const credentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

      const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        `https://${ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`,
        credentials
      );
      let i = 1;
      for await (const container of blobServiceClient.listContainers()) {
        console.log(`Container ${i++}: ${container.name}`);
      }
    }
  }
```

===========================

(Reference: [SharedKeyCredential is not a constructor - Azure Blob Storage + Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873972/sharedkeycredential-is-not-a-constructor-azure-blob-storage-nodejs))

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Shared Access Signature (SAS) or OAuth Token for your authentications as  SharedKeyCredential is only available in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use StorageSharedKEyCredential?

Simple answer is that you can't. Because your code would run in the browser (or in other words on the client side), using StorageSharedKeyCredential will expose your account key to everybody and that's a huge security risk.

In case of using JS SDK from a browser-based application, you would need to use `Shared Access Signature`. You can find an example of the same here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob#with-sas-token.